# The gradients are all 0 when backwards and the parameters didnot change at all

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, mlp, policy-gradient-descent

I implement the policy gradient method to learn the unknown function( which is a 10 loop sum function here), but the model did not update. The learning data is input and the target. func2 include the MLP model which to predict the target number. The code is the following:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import random
import torch.optim as opt
import torch
from torch.autograd.variable import Variable

class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 8)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(8, 8)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(8, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x=F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x=F.relu(x)
        x=self.fc3(x)
        x=F.sigmoid(x)
        return x

def assertEqual(label, pre_number):
    reward = -torch.sum((label - pre_number).pow(2))
    return reward
def func_mulsum(model, s,scalar,n_loop):
    c=s
    for i in range(n_loop):
        c = model(c)
    return c

def train_test_data(n_loop):
    nums=100
    rate=0.7
    train_data=np.zeros((int(nums*rate),2))
    test_data=np.zeros((int(nums*(1-rate)),2))
    data=random.sample(range(nums),nums)


    train=data[:int(nums*rate)]
    test = data[int(nums*rate):]

    train_data[:,0]=train
    test_data[:,0]=test

    for i,ans in enumerate(train):
        for j in range(n_loop):
            ans+=j
        train_data[i,1]=ans

    for i,ans1 in enumerate(test):
        for j in range(n_loop):
            ans1+=j
        test_data[i,1]=ans1
    return train_data,test_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_loop=10
    iterations=10
    learn_data, test_case = train_test_data(n_loop)
    model=MLP()
    optim=opt.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.05)

    for i in range(iterations):
        reward_sum=0
        learn_data = torch.FloatTensor(learn_data)

        for j,data in enumerate(learn_data[:,0]):
            data=data.unsqueeze(0)

            label=learn_data[j,1]
            optim.zero_grad()
            pre=func_mulsum(model,data,255,n_loop)

            p_norm = torch.normal(pre, std=0.000000001)
            reward = assertEqual(p_norm,label)

           # print(p_norm,label)
            loss=reward*(torch.log(p_norm)*-1)

            loss.backward()

            reward_sum += loss
            optim.step()
            for para in model.parameters():
                pass
            print(para)

        print('reward_mean............................', reward_sum)
```

I could not find the reason why the gradients are all 0. this question confused me for 2 days. Anyone can help me?